# change color of anchor tag in another div when custom radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML code below:

```
<input type="radio" name="form-radio" id="workshops" value="high" checked>
<label id="workshoping" for="workshops">Workshops</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="form-radio" id="courses" value="option2">
<label for="courses">Courses</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="form-radio" id="exclusive" value="option3">
<label for="exclusive">Exclusivess</label><br>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <H2><a href="#" id="workshopcl">WorkShops</a></H2>
    <span>Short Term</span>
    <span>Single Session</span>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 coursescl">
    <H2><a href="#" class="">Courses</a></H2>
    <span>Long Term</span>
    <span>Multi Sessions</span>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 exclusivecl">
    <H2><a href="#" class="">Exclusives</a></H2>
    <span>Skilhippo's Exclusives</span>
</div>
```

this is my  CSS for custom radio buttons

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

label {
    font-family: $verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-left:13px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

input {
    border: 2px solid $black;
    border-radius:0;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding:5px;
    color:$dark_grey;
    @media (min-width: $tablet) and (max-width: $tablet-max) {
        /* Media Query Between Screen 768px and 980px  */ 
        width:124px !important;  
    }
}

input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 9px;
    margin: -3px 8px 0 3px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15px;
} 

input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    content:"\2022";
    text-align: center;
}

.high {
    color:yellow;
}
```

how do i use the Jquery to change the color of Workshops text in `id="workshopcl"` when I check the workshop radio button

SO please kindly help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method it will work with all three checkboxes checked and add background to the titles

```
$('input').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        var dt = $(this).data('title')
        $('h2 a').css('background-color', 'white')
        $('#' + dt).css('background-color', 'red')
        console.log(dt)
    }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sEwM6/148/)

Comment: @user2963346 if it helps accept as answer , glad to help :-)

Comment: thanks a lot this works fine. but how do i do it  by adding the class "high" mentioned in CSS

Answer (score 1):

Add an `onclick` event to the radio button like:

```
<input type="radio" name="form-radio" id="workshops" value="high" onclick="changecolor()" checked>
```

Write the js function like :

```
function changecolor()
{
$('#workshopcl').css('color', 'red');
}
```

This will add css to the element with id `workshopcl`.

Answer (score 0):

In pure CSS the selector is :

```
#workshops:checked ~ div #workshopcl {color:red;}
```

You can use this selector in your jQuery
if you set this id on the div container, you can select any childs within that box : 
you can select container from class too :
**http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Cmrxj/**

```
#workshops:checked ~ div#workshopcl,
#workshops:checked ~ div#workshopcl a,
#courses:checked ~ div.coursescl ,
#courses:checked ~ div.coursescl a,
#exclusive:checked ~ div.exclusivecl ,
#exclusive:checked ~ div.exclusivecl a
{color:red;}
```

html for workshop becomes:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" id="workshopcl">
    <H2><a href="#">WorkShops</a></H2>
    <span>Short Term</span>
    <span>Single Session</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $('#workshops').on('click',function (){ 
     if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $('#workshopcl').css('color', 'green');
     else
        $('#workshopcl').css('color', 'black'); 
   });
```

Happy Coding :)